# For-in cicle gives back only last result in array.push

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, for-in-loop

I use Vue.js 2 and I have an array of objects taken from an API (https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction this one) that is linked to a variable that is the v-model of an input. So anytime the variable changes the array changes too with a function that calls the API when @keyup.
The array is about movies and TV shows.
It has a structure like this:

```
(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: we]
0:
backdrop_path: (...)
first_air_date: (...)
genre_ids: Array(3)
0: 18
1: 80
2: 9648
length: 3
__ob__: we {value: Array(3), dep: ce, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
genres_name: ["Mistero"]
id: (...)
media_type: (...)
name: (...)
origin_country: (...)
original_language: (...)
original_name: (...)
overview: (...)
popularity: (...)
poster_path: (...)
vote_average: (...)
vote_count: (...)
```

This array provides me useful information about movies and tv-series, but it doesn't give me back the genres, not the names of these at least, but ids related to them yes in the key `genre_ids: Array(3)`. Now, I've called another API that provides a genre list like this:

```
(19) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
id: 28
name: "Azione"
__proto__: Object
1:
id: 12
name: "Avventura"
__proto__: Object
2: {id: 16, name: "Animazione"}
3: {id: 35, name: "Commedia"}
4: {id: 80, name: "Crime"}
5: {id: 99, name: "Documentario"}
6: {id: 18, name: "Dramma"}
7: {id: 10751, name: "Famiglia"}
8: {id: 14, name: "Fantasy"}
9: {id: 36, name: "Storia"}
10: {id: 27, name: "Horror"}
11: {id: 10402, name: "Musica"}
12: {id: 9648, name: "Mistero"}
13: {id: 10749, name: "Romance"}
14: {id: 878, name: "Fantascienza"}
15: {id: 10770, name: "televisione film"}
16: {id: 53, name: "Thriller"}
17: {id: 10752, name: "Guerra"}
18: {id: 37, name: "Western"}
length: 19
__proto__: Array(0)
```

What I want is to compare the two array's ids and pass the genre list's genre's name to the first array to every object, so I did this way

```
const newArray = this.searchResults.map ((element) => {
                        let objectResults = element.genre_ids;
                        console.log('objectResults', objectResults);
                        let object = element;
                        console.log('single-object', object);

                        this.genresName.forEach(genre => {
                            if (objectResults.includes(genre.id) ) {
                                object.genres_name = [];
                                for(var key in genre) {
                                    if (key == 'name') {
                                        console.log('key', genre[key]);
                                        let keyName = '';
                                        keyName = keyName + genre[key];
                                        object.genres_name.push(keyName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        console.log(this.searchResults);
```

My problem is that I can read correctly every genre's name for every show, so id comparison works, but when it comes to push them in every element of the first array, only the last one is pushed and only one. Most shows should have more than one genre, because they have more than one id in `genre_ids: Array`, but I can obtain only one of them and always the last

Comment: Hi, Try using `splice` to push the items in the array.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this way but it leaves the array empty `object.genres_name.splice(0, keyName);`

Comment: Hi, Have a look at this article (https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-splice/#:~:text=The%20splice()%20method%20allows,indicates%20the%20elements%20to%20insert.) about the inserting element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a prettier way to do this, but this works. This will create a new array in the movies array, called `genreNames`, which will include the corresponding genre names.

```js
const genres = [
  { id: 12, name: "Avventura" },
  { id: 16, name: "Animazione" },
  { id: 35, name: "Commedia" },
  { id: 80, name: "Crime" },
  { id: 99, name: "Documentario" },
  { id: 18, name: "Dramma" },
];

const movies = [
  { genre_ids: [12, 16], name: "Movie 1" },
  { genre_ids: [80, 99], name: "Movie 2" },
  { genre_ids: [18, 12, 99], name: "Movie 3" },
];

// our final result
let finalArray = [];
movies.map(element => {
  // create a temp array for the genres
  let genreNames = []
  element.genre_ids.map(genre => {
    // each genreid from the movie, find the corresponding name from the genres array
    genreNames.push(genres.find(val => val.id === genre).name)
  })
  // finally push the original movie and the newly create array for the names
  finalArray.push({ ...element, genreNames })
})
console.log(finalArray);
```